# c++ find char in vector of unsigned chars

Tags: c++, vector, find, char, unsigned

I have the problem with the following code:

```
message is vector<unsigned char>

vector<unsigned char>::iterator pos = message.begin();
vector<unsigned char>::iterator start = message.begin();
vector<unsigned char>::iterator end = message.end();

pos = find(start, end, ' ');
```

I got the error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘find(std::vector<unsigned char>::iterator&, std::vector<unsigned char>::iterator&, char)’
```

Comment: Did you `#include <algorithm>` ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Are you including `<algorithm>`?

Comment: and don't forget the "using namespace std" or "std::find"

Comment: @MerickOWA: I've assumed that he's `using namespace std` by his `vector` code.

Comment: @MerickOWA I don't think he forgot `using namespace std;` or else it would not have recognized it as `std::vector`

Comment: Thank you a lot!!!! I did not check my headers. I deleted algorithm by accident. Stupid mistake.